# Recognize array or string with a regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have a file with this structure:

```
[25-02-2016 16:55:09.497203] [exception] SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or 
view not found: 1146 Table 'test.pdd_userss' doesn't exist 
   0: array(
      'Stack' => 'exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.pdd_userss' doesn't exist' in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\database.php:57
   Stack trace:
   #0 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\database.php(57): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM p...')
   #1 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\models\tests_model.php(31): Database->select('SELECT * FROM p...')
   #2 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\controllers\test.php(43): Tests_Model->selectData()
   #3 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\router.php(158): Test->selectUser()
   #4 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\map.php(52): Router->submit()
   #5 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\system\api.php(107): Map->init_get()
   #6 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\boot.php(21): Api->init()
   #7 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\index.php(18): Boot->__construct()
   #8 {main}',
      'ID' => 'john foo'
   )
[25-02-2016 16:55:09.497857] [info] Sistema executed. 
   0: array(
      'ID' => 'john foo'
   )
[25-02-2016 16:55:13.255716] [info] System done.
```

Now for the first two cases I have no problem for deserialize the structure as follow (the first two trace) the third trace isn't printed I put this in the example is the structure that I want to achieve:

```
{
"trace": [2]
0:  {
"date": "25-02-2016 17:02:31.830305"
"type": "exception"
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.pdd_userss' doesn't exist"
"ID": "" <- THE ID ISN'T DISPLAYED
}-
1:  {
"date": "25-02-2016 17:02:31.831140"
"type": "info"
"message": "system done."
"ID": "john foo"
}-
-
 .... OTHER CONTENT
}
```

but for the  `error` nothing is displayed 'cause the `regex` fail to deserialize the data. This is my code:

```
 $fh = file_get_contents($file);

 if(!$fh) { throw new Exception("Not found"); }

 $content = array(); 
 $content["trace"] = array();

 preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\][\s]*?\[(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s.]+(?:\d+[^\']*\'ID\'[ ]*=>[ ]*\'(.*)\')?/',
 $fh, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

 for($i = 0; $i < count($regs[0]); $i++)
 {
       $content['trace'][] = array(
       'date'    => $regs[1][$i],
       'type'    => trim($regs[2][$i]),
       'message' => trim($regs[3][$i]),
       'ID'      => trim($regs[4][$i]),
            );
  }

  return $content;
```

How you can see in the first case I have an array like this:

```
0: array(
  'ID' => 'john foo'
```

)

and infact the id is displayed correctly, but in the second case I have a simple string: `'ID' => 'john foo'`

the string isn't displayed, so how I can recognize this two case?

Answer (score 0):

I think all you are looking for is a simple [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) just before your regex...and then you can write an if statement to handle if it's an array or not...

```
  $content = array(); 
  $content["trace"] = array();

  if (is_array($regs)) {
  // it's an array.
  } else {
  // not an array.
  }
  ...etc....
```

**EDIT:** Whoops...I should have said *after* the regex. After looking at the php docs the array you want isn't created until afterwards.

```
preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\][\s]*?\[(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s.]+(?:\d+[^\']*\'ID\'[ ]*=>[ ]*\'(.*)\')?/', $fh, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

  if (is_array($regs)) {
  // it's an array.
  } else {
  // not an array.
  }
  ...etc....
```

You could also try

```
if (empty($regs[4][0])) {}
```

and handle a different set of regex from there.

Comment: Sorry for the intromission, but I guess that also with your condition the problem isn't fixed.. the regex is the problem

Comment: The problem is on the regex not in the `array`